# In Drupal 7 Commerce, where do you send an order completion confirmation email to administrators or store owners?

Tags: 7, commerce

I just noticed that I wasnt getting any confirmation emails when there is a order completion. Where do I set this up so I can get an email notifying me of a completed order for Drupal 7 commerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default for Drupal Commerce (not the Aquia version) there is no email connectivity set up for order complete confirmations - yes there is a rule which defines the message that is sent and when it is sent, but the third party module Commerce Message available here https://www.drupal.org/project/Commerce_message must be installed. There is no place in the rule which allows configuration of a specific e-mail address. This functionality also requires the Message and Message Notify modules

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is available in the rules provided by the drupal commerce at (`admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules`):

```
admin -> commerce -> config -> checkout -> rules -> "Send an order notification e-mail"
```

[image]

Configuration of recipient email address including the admin address you want the order confirmation sent to can be done at this place.

Also you can check the doc for commerce order mail: https://drupal.org/node/2061215

Comment: Exactly. Everyone that happens on checkout completion can be found there in the checkout completion rules, including this default rule to send an order notification e-mail to the customer. It's up to you to edit this to send a different type of e-mail to the customer or an additional notification to an administrator.